# How do I Save the Heap (Dump to a File) in Eclipse?

Tags: java, memory-leaks, heap-memory

I'm getting this error when I run or debug my GA/AI from MyEclipse:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

eclipse.ini looks like this:

```
-showsplash com.genuitec.myeclipse.product
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize 256m
-vmargs
-Xms128m
-Xmx512m
-Duser.language=en 
-XX:PermSize=128M 
-XX:MaxPermSize=256M
```

MyEclipse is called like this:

```
"C:\Program Files\MyEclipse 6.0\eclipse\eclipse.exe" -vm "C:\Program Files\MyEclipse 6.0\jre\bin\javaw.exe"  -vmargs -Xms1448M -Xmx1448M
```

bumping the vm settings up from this:

```
"C:\Program Files\MyEclipse 6.0\eclipse\eclipse.exe" -vm "C:\Program Files\MyEclipse 6.0\jre\bin\javaw.exe"  -vmargs -Xms80M -Xmx1024M
```

has had no effect. So I'm trying to get it to dump the heap to a file, but placing these:

```
-XX:+HeapDumpOnCtrlBreak
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
```

in the Program arguments has had no effect. How do I get something to work with more memory usage analysis? jstack, for instance, is not currently available on Windows platforms. And using SendSignal has no effect that I can see.

[image: a screen shot]

Comment: try upping XXMaxPermSize as well

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are a number of ways to get heap dumps.  Here are some I've used:

1. `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` *should* get you dump if you hit your OOM.
2. Connect with [VisualVM](https://visualvm.dev.java.net/) (free) and use its GUI to force a heap dump
3. Use one of the many good commercial profilers (JProfiler, YourKit, ...)
4. Use jmap (see below) to force a dump from a running process

If you're running Java 6, [jmap](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jmap.html) should work on Windows.  This might be useful if you want to dump the heap and you haven't hit your OOM.  Use Windows Task Manager to find the pid of your Java app, and in a console run this:

```
jmap -dump:format=b,file=c:\heap.bin <pid>
```

In addition to VisualVM, the [Eclipse Memory Analyzer](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) (also free) can help you analyze what's eating up all the space once you've got the dump.

Comment: When I Run the Main function, an application is created in VisualVM that does not have dump functionality: you can't Heap Dump, Thread Dump, there is no Heap tab, etc.

Comment: If -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError did work, what would it look like on my system?

Comment: jps outputs the pid process as well

Comment: Your jmap syntax worked like a charm in Windows 7 with Java 7. Thank you!

Comment: with Java VisualVM I created a heap dump but how then can I save it to a file?

Answer (score 2):

`-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` should be put in "`VM Arguments`" not "`Program Arguments`"

Answer (score 1):

You can monitor memory usages with JConsole.

The [jstat](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/share/jstat.html) also will help.